# check String contains inside HashTable Value

Tags: java, hashtable

```
1=[Fletcher Christian, No, Visualisation of Egocentric Networks, Exploring the Irish Political Landscape on Twitter, Twitter Network Analysis, A Web-Based Server Energy Model Generator, Recommending Movies Using Curated IMDb Lists, Travel Planner for Commuters, Analysis of urban street networks - constructing a dual representation, Biography Reading Media Assistant]
```

I Have `hash-table` like above.i want to find whether **Fletcher Christian** is contained inside the `Hash-Table` value

here value is a vector

Comment: Using [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) and [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)??? Both have been mostly obsolete since Java 1.2 ***(1998)***, replaced by [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Javadoc says so: *"it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`"* and *"it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply go over all values and check :

```
static boolean contains (Hashtable <Integer, Vector <String>> map, String value){
    for (Vector<String> values : map.values()){
        if (values.contains(value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In Java 8 you can do it with a single row:

```
static boolean contains (Hashtable <Integer, Vector<String>> map, String value){
    return map.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains(value));
}
```

Comment: According to question, `List` should be `Vector`.

Comment: Yes, already changed it. It doesn't really matter though,  because `Vector` implements `List`....

Comment: Ahh, but `Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>` is not compatible with `Hashtable<Integer, Vector<String>>`. To make it compatible, you'd could say `Map<Integer, ? extends List<String>>`

Comment: Error ocuured "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector"

Comment: @Janukasamaranyake Grisha was guessing at your datatype, since you didn't explicitly specify what it is. You said *"I Have `hash-table` like above"*, which we read as `Hashtable`. It seems to have an integer key, so `Integer`. You say *"value is a vector"*, which we read as `Vector`. It seems to have text elements, so `String`. Hence, guess is `Hashtable<Integer, Vector<String>>`. If you get *"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector"*, then that is not the type or you messed up in code not shown. In both cases, outside visible code so we can't help.

Comment: thanx,i  fix that issue